# JavaScript get string from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to get a string from a `MySQL` database and then split it into an array with `JavaScript`. Here is the code that I have so far.

**Ajax Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "updateDropdown.php",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {option_id:newName},
    type: 'get',
    success: function(r){
        var html = "<select name='" + newName + "_one_dressing' required><option value=''>Select...</option>";
        var array1 = r.split(", ");
        for(i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
            // I use array1[i].toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_") to convert "Salad Cream" to the id "salad_cream", etc.
            html += "<option value='" + array1[i].toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_") + "'>" + array1[i] + "</option>";
        }
        html += "</select>";
        el2.html(html);
    }
});
```

`newName` is just a string, `el2` is just an element that I get from the document.

**updateDropdown.php:**

```
<?php

include "/home/pi/config.php";
$id = $_GET['option_id'];
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", $name, $pass, "items");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Error!";
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT options FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
echo mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];
?>
```

The config.php file just contains a $name and $pass variable. I know that it connects successfully. It meant to display a drop down in the element. In my `MySQL` database, I have this string: "Mayonnaise, Salad Cream, Chutney, No Dressing" I want the drop down to have 5 options: the first is a select option to prompt the user, and then each other option is the options in the array.

Thanks,

Comment: In your success handler, are you getting the response you expect in the r variable if you log it with console.log?

Comment: What is going wrong? What do you see if you use browser developer tools to do "inspect element" on this dropdown before and after your success function is invoked? Can you use console.log() calls and trace what's going on? Again, use the browser's developer tools to view the console.